# How to avoid flutter page scroll up when the keyboard comes up

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get input from these `TextField`. When I focus the `TextField` the keyboard comes up and page scroll up. I do not need that scrolling. How can I avoid this?

[image: Normal View]

[image: After TextField Focusing]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get better idea follow this reference link : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html

```
 return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,
      body: Container(),
    )
```

Comment: Strange, I answered first, still you got 2 upvotes + acceptance, bad luck Haha.

Comment: let's try next one for better luck bro.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  ...
)
```

From docs:

> For example, if there is an onscreen keyboard displayed above the scaffold, the body can be resized to avoid overlapping the keyboard, which prevents widgets inside the body from being obscured by the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

textFiled when the keyboard opens then scroll your TextFiled to use SingleChildScrollView in your main Column Widget Wrap it.

`SingleChildScrollView( keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag, reverse: true, child: Column( children: []), );`